# Does the Dagesh forte really replace a double letter?

Tags: tefilla, tanach, grammar-dikduk

I have read about the Dagesh Forte and how it doubles a letter in Tanach.

For example, הָלֵּלוּ has a dagesh forte in the לֵּ.

If this dagesh was not there would there really be two ל instead?

Also does the dagesh change the way you pronounce the ל when learning Torah and praying?

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. The policy is that Hebrew language questions are only on-topic as they pertain to Judaism; not all questions about Hebrew are about Judaism. Cf. [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4372/9682).

Comment: Ben I've edited the question to make it clearer how it's on-topic. If this version doesn't quite match your intent, please [edit] further. Also, could you please [edit] in a citation for where you found "הָלֵּלוּ", in particular?

Comment: Do you mean הַלְּלוּ or הַלָּלוּ? I don't recognize הָלֵּלוּ  as a word

Comment: Re "really replace a double letter" and "would there really be two" - there is a special case of _d'geshim_ in which a "vestigial" _dagesh_ can appear in the letter after a dropped nasal sound. If the nasal letter was a _nun_ and the next letter is a _nun_ then the placement of a _dagesh_ in it could have the effect of really standing in for two of the same letter in a row.

Answer (score 1):

A [Dagesh Forte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagesh#Dagesh_Hazak) indicates the consonant is to be [geminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination). If you want to call that "doubling" go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the pronunciation of a consonant that is marked with a dagesh hazak is doubled, so you read it as closing the previous syllable and then starting the next syllable.

This comes up in the daily mitzvah of reading Shma:

[Mishneh Torah, Sefer Ahavah, Hilkhot Kriat Shma 2:9](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2102.htm#9):

> כיצד מדקדק--ייזהר שלא ירפה החזק, ולא יחזק הרפה
>
> How do you [implement the requirement to] be precise [in reading the
>   Shma]? You take care not to pronounce [a letter] marked [by a dagesh] as
>   [if it were] not marked [by a dagesh] and to not pronounce an unmarked 
>   [letter] as if it were marked.

Comment: Is that Halakha not about BGDKPT? How do you know it refers to Dagesh Hazak?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I assumed that it meant both kinds of dagesh: kal and hazak. But I don't know for sure.